# How to hide navbar-toggle in jQuery when the search button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with my website. In the header there are 2 buttons with 2 different codes ( 1 for open/close the menu and 1 for open/close the search  ).

[image: Two buttons preview]

This code works nice, it open and close the menu.

```
! function(a) {
    a(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function() {
        a(this).toggleClass("open"), a("#navigation").slideToggle(400)
    }), a(".navigation-menu>li").slice(-1).addClass("last-elements"), a(".crspnt").on("click", function(b) {
        a(window).width() < 992 && (b.preventDefault(), a(this).parent("li").toggleClass("open").find(".submenu:first").toggleClass("open"))
    })
}
```

Also this code works nice, it open the search box:

```
(jQuery), $("search-btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#show-search-box").css("display", "block")
});
```

The problem is that when the menu is open and I open the search, it looks very bad.

I need to change the 2nd code ( of the search ) and add the function that when the search button is clicked the menu close.

Any Idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class from the menu:

```
(jQuery), $("search-btn").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".navbar-toggle").removeClass('open');
    $("#show-search-box").css("display", "block")
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have just try but it says: ReferenceError: a is not defined